# How to pass a parameter and cast to a certain data type inside a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, identifier

I'm attempting to write a plpgsql function to insert a record into a table that expects some timestamps in certain columns. Here is the function:

```
create or replace function insert_slot(created_by varchar
                                     , version bigint
                                     , bsv_id bigint
                                     , start_date varchar) returns int as $$
declare
    last_id int := (select id from appointments order by id desc limit 1) + 1;

begin
    insert into appointments (
        id,
        created,
        created_by,
        version,
        bsv_id,
        usrn,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        status,
        request_priority_name,
        reservation_expiry,
        day_of_week
    )values (
        last_id,
        now(),
        created_by,
        version,
        bsv_id,
        'UN-' || last_id,
        to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp @start_date)),
        to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp '2017-2-12 10:30:00')),
        'OCCUPIED',
        'ROUTINE',
        to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp '2017-3-19 10:30:00')),
        1
    );

    return last_id;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from insert_slot('Brad', 2, 70000, '2017-2-12 10:00:00');
```

This works fine when I am passing a literal string for the date format, but not for a parameter:

```
to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp @start_date)),
to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp '2017-2-12 10:30:00')),
```

When I try to use `@start_date` or `start_date` instead of the literal string I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "timestamp" does not exist
> LINE 21:    to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp @start_date)),
> ```

Can someone enlighten me as to the correct syntax to use? I've found plenty of posts online about using parameters but can't find anything that addresses why I can't pass through the function parameter to epoch from timestamp.

Comment: At least Postgresql has type serial and bigserial. That creaste sequence and set to field next value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1.

Do not use a `@` character to prepend variables. That's SQL-Server or MySQL syntax (and maybe others) and illegal in Postgres SQL or PL/pgSQL code.

PL/pgSQL variable names follow the same rules as SQL identifiers. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (`a-z`, but also
>   letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
>   (`_`). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
>   letters, underscores, digits (`0`-`9`), or dollar signs (`$`).

So <strike>`@start_date`</strike> is a syntax error.

### 2.

In this expression:

```
to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp '2017-2-12 10:30:00')),
```

`timestamp` is the *data type* of the immediately following string literal.

But this notation is not allowed for run-time type conversions. So this is a syntax error:

<strike>`to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp start_date))`</strike>

You can use an explicit type cast instead:

```
to_timestamp(extract(epoch from start_date::timestamp))
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC)

> The `::`, `CAST()`, and function-call syntaxes can also be used to specify
>   run-time type conversions of arbitrary expressions, as discussed in
>   [Section 4.2.9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). To avoid syntactic ambiguity, the `type 'string'` syntax
>   can only be used to specify the type of a simple literal constant.

---

In your particular case it would be smarter / cleaner to define the function parameter as `date` or `timestamp` to begin with - depends on what kind of data you plan to pass to the function. Your parameter name indicates a `date`, but your example indicates a `timestamp`.

Either way, you don't need to cast that later. [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) also accepts `date` and casts it to `timestamp` automatically.

Comment: Many thanks :) That cast worked a treat and I'll take on board the advice about the variable types and tinker with it later.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Just found time to read your reply in more detail. Thanks for taking the time to give such a thorough explanation. The comments on the timestamp being the datatype of the string and the syntax I was using only being good for simple literals etc. was particularly helpful. Many thanks :)

Comment: Something not right.
`select to_timestamp( extract(epoch from '2022-02-26 09:59:25.834706+05:30'::timestamp));` I got `2022-02-26 15:29:25.834706+05:30`   
But `select to_timestamp( extract(epoch from '2022-02-26 09:59:25.834706+05:30'::timestamptz));` I got `2022-02-26 09:59:25.834706+05:30`   
to_timestamp ( text, text ) → timestamp with time zone

Comment: @Erwin from timestamp to timestamptz without mention timezone is not right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use serial/bigserial for `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE appointments(id bigserial PRIMARY KEY, ...
```

Also is better to pass start_date as timestsamp.

```
create or replace function insert_slot(created_by varchar, version bigint, bsv_id bigint, start_date timestsamp) returns int as $$
```

For access to function's argument in postgresql you just use its name. Also you can call it via `<function_name>.<variable name>`. It might be useful when arguments of your function has the same name as column in tables (as is in your function). To avoid this you can add something (for example `v_`) to names. Also you do not need too complicate construction as `to_timestamp(extract(epoch from timestamp '2017-3-19 10:30:00'))`. Also you can use just sql function.
Improved variant of function:

```
create table appointments (
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            created timestamp,
            created_by text,
            version text,
            bsv_id int8,
            usrn text,
            start_date timestamp,
            end_date timestamp,
            status text,
            request_priority_name text,
            reservation_expiry timestamp,
            day_of_week int2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_usrn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $sql$
BEGIN
    NEW.usrn := 'UN' || NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$sql$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_usrn BEFORE INSERT ON appointments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_usrn();

create or replace function insert_slot(v_created_by varchar, v_version bigint, v_bsv_id bigint, v_start_date timestamp) returns int as $$
        insert into appointments (
            created,
            created_by,
            version,
            bsv_id,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            status,
            request_priority_name,
            reservation_expiry,
            day_of_week
        )values (
            now(),
            v_created_by,
            v_version,
            v_bsv_id,
            v_start_date,
            '2017-2-12 10:30:00',
            'OCCUPIED',
            'ROUTINE',
            '2017-3-19 10:30:00',
            1
        ) RETURNING id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

For checking results:

```
select * from insert_slot('Brad', 2, 70000, '2017-2-12 10:00:00');
SELECT * FROM appointments;



 id |          created           | created_by | version | bsv_id | usrn |     start_date      |      end_date       |  status  | request_priority_name | reservation_expiry  | day_of_week 
----+----------------------------+------------+---------+--------+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------
  1 | 2017-02-05 17:30:59.800305 | Brad       | 2       |  70000 | UN1  | 2017-02-12 10:00:00 | 2017-02-12 10:30:00 | OCCUPIED | ROUTINE               | 2017-03-19 10:30:00 |           1
```

Comment: That's great advice, many thanks for the help. This is my first attempt at writing a function like this so all advice on good practice is very welcome. Once again, thanks for the help! :)